# How to get level(depth) number of two connected nodes in neo4j

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm using neo4j as a graph database to store user's connections detail into this. here I want to show the level of one user with respect to another user in their connections like Linkedin. for example- first layer connection, second layer connection, third layer and above the third layer shows 3+. but I don't know how this happens using neo4j. i searched for this but couldn't find any solution for this. if anybody knows about this then please help me to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the shortest "connection level" between *2 specific people*, just get the shortest path and add 1:

```
MATCH path = shortestpath((p1:Person)-[*..]-(p2:Person))
WHERE p1.id = 1 AND p2.id = 2
RETURN LENGTH(path) + 1 AS level
```

*NOTE: You may want to put a reasonable upper bound on the [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern (e.g., `[*..6]`) to avoid having the query taking too long or running out of memory in a large DB). You should probably ignore very distant connections anyway.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

it would be something like this

```
// get all persons  (or users)
MATCH (p:Person) 

// create a set of unique combinations , assuring that you do
// not do double work
WITH COLLECT(p) AS personList
UNWIND personList AS personA
UNWIND personList AS personB

WITH personA,personB
WHERE id(personA) < id(personB)

// find the shortest path between any two nodes
MATCH path=shortestPath( (personA)-[:LINKED_TO*]-(personB) )

// return the distance  ( = path length) between the two nodes
RETURN personA.name AS nameA,
       personB.name AS nameB,
       CASE WHEN length(path) > 3 THEN '3+'
            ELSE toString(length(path))
       END AS distance
```

Comment: can you please explain this query, it not a bit clear to understand

Comment: @TecoreDemo  I have added some, but may I suggest that you do some reading on the basics of Cypher?  https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/  is a good point to start.